# Running Multiple testng suites in parallel with different parameters for each of those suites

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng

I am trying to run multiple testng suites parallely with different parameters with cucumber.With each tesng suite am trying to pass different browsers,testinfo and so forth.I would like to acheive this through maven command line options.
I have followed the post at https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/parallel-execution-of-multiple-testng-suites/#comment-1723. What i would like to do is run the suites in parallel with different set of JVM parameters.

I have tried the following way to achieve  the same and this just launches one firefox browser to execute tests and ignores chrome browser totally (does not even run sequentially)

```
mvn verify  -Dcucumber.options="--tags @123" -DGrid="false" -Dbrowser="chrome" 
-Durl="https://abc.xyz.com" -Dtestinfo="R3.0-Regression-chrome" -DNewuser="123test1"  
-DsuiteXmlFile=Chrometestng.xml,-Dcucumber.options="--tags @123" -DGrid="false" 
-Dbrowser="firefox" -Durl="https://abc.xyz.com" -Dtestinfo="R3.0-Regression-FF" 
-DNewuser="123test2" -DsuiteXmlFile=FFtestng.xml  -Dthreads=2
```

My sure fire is as below

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.22.0</version>
<configuration>
    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
            <value>${threads}</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</configuration>
```

My testNg is as below

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.testng</groupId>
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<version>6.14.2</version>
<scope>test</scope>
```

My chrometestng.xml and Chrometestrunner as below (FFtestng.xml and FFrunner is similar to chrome except for change in suite/test name)

```
<suite name="ChromeSuite" parallel="false">
<test name="ChromeTest">
    <classes>
        <class name="abc.runner.ChromeTestRunner"></class>
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

```
  @RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)
  @ExtendedCucumberOptions(
    jsonReport = "target/cucumber.json",
    detailedReport = true,
    jsonUsageReport = "target/cucumber-usage.json",
    toPDF = true,
    excludeCoverageTags = {"@flaky" },
    includeCoverageTags = {"@passed" },
    reportPrefix = "abc_Report",
   outputFolder = "abc_Reports/PDFReports/${testinfo}/DATE(yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-SS)/")
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { /*"html:target/cucumber-html-report",*/
    "json:target/cucumber.json"/*, "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
    "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json", "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml"*/ },
    features={"src/test/resources/featurefiles"},strict = false, dryRun=false,
    glue = {"abc_stepdefinitions"},
    tags = {"@123"})
@Test
public class ChromeTestRunner extends ExtendedTestNGRunner {    
}
```

when i try this

```
mvn verify DsuiteXmlFile=Chrometestng.xml,FFtestng.xml -Dthreads=2
```

It alteast launches two chrome browsers in parallel.

I am trying to figure out whats incorrect about my approach and what would be the right way to accomplish this. If this is not possible, is there a way i can can have multiple test tags (chrome/ff/ie) within just one suite and pass test level info separately for each of those tests from maven command line.

My doubt is  i may be overwriting JVM values as in -Dbrowser="chrome", gets overwritten by -Dbrowser="firefox"

***More Details***

I am basically trying to do cross browser testing with cucumber in parallel.In this case i can essentially have 3 test tags in single suite (each for chrome,ff,ie), but my concern is how to pass parameters like browser, testinfo (unique to each test) seperately from maven command line .will something like -Dchrometest.browser="chrome" and -Dfirefoxtest.browser="firefox" work here. Right now i have 3 batch file for each browsers and invoking 3 simultaneoulsy. So 3 seperate JVM instance.Downside is cpu utilization is always 100 % and IE invariably fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog that you have linked with this question was created by me.

Coming back to answering your question. What you ask is kind of impossible without putting in some ugly hacks.
The reason why I said that it's not possible is because you need to ensure that the number of suites matches with the comma separated values that are part of the JVM argument.

So lets say your thread count was `2` and you passed in two browser flavors as comma separated values via the JVM argument, the parsing logic would still not be able to distinguish if the first value is to be retrieved or if the second value is to be retrieved.

One approach that you could do is as below:

1. Define a class which is synchronized and is a singleton.
2. This class when invoked would basically be able to parse the JVM argument  (browser flavors that are being passed in this case) and return back one browser value for every invocation. So if it were to be invoked twice, it would attempt to return back two values from the parsed JVM argument (which is comma separated values).
3. Now within your suite you would basically just query this new singleton class. So every querying would return back a unique browser flavor.

Comment: Hello Krishnan,Thanks for detailing out.This seems a bit complicated as you say.if you can put code samples (in your blog post), it would be of great help. I have added more details to original post, if you think that's doable please do let me know

Comment: That is not the scope of that blog. The blog's intent was only to show how parallel suites can be executed using TestNG. For your question, I believe I have answered it and outlined a possible approach  that you can adopt as well  Please accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing this using Virtual Machines. Use a different virtual machine for each different set of jvm parameters. This should simplify things as each set of features will be isolated

Comment: So you are suggesting using different VMs' for each of different browsers .But what i am trying to achieve is have one central HUB and then spawn browsers in Windows/MAC platform with me getting all reports back to HUB machine..

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve and am suggesting that using VM's would make things easier. You could get the reports back from the VM's and integrate them if thats whats required. I believe you will find it very difficult to get a single run of cucumber to do what you want.